# what is the best way in spark to get each group as a new dataframe and pass on another function in loop?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v, and I'm trying to do find quantiles, i.e. percentile 0, percentile 25, etc, on each column of my given data.

My data:

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  id|     date|      revenue|con_dist_1| con_dist_2| state  |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|   TX   |
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|   AZ   |
|  10|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|   TX   |
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|   TX   |
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|   AZ   |
|  10|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|   CA   |
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|   CA   |
|  10|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|   CA   |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

I would get the states to calculate i.e

```
val states = Seq("CA","AZ");
val cols = Seq("con_dist_1" ,"con_dist_2")
```

for each given state I need to fetch data from source table and calculate percentiles only for  the given columns.

I'm trying as below

```
for( state <- states){

     for( col <- cols){
        // pecentile calculation
     }
}
```

this is too slow, when doing group by "state" wont get another columns like revenue, date and id.. how to get those?

How to find the quantiles on the columns "con_dist_1" & "con_dist_2" for each state? So what is the best way which scales well on cluster?

What is the best way to handle this use-case?

Expected result

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|state|col1_quantile_1|col1_quantile_2|col1_quantile_3|col2_quantile_1|col2_quantile_2|col2_quantile_3|
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   AZ|              4|              4|              4|    0.816039063|    0.816039063|    0.816039063|
|   TX|              4|              6|              6|    0.019875458|    0.019875458|    0.082049528|
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I found the `percentile_approx` function from the hive context, so you don't need to use the `stat` functions.

```
val states = Seq("CA", "AZ")
val cols = Seq("con_dist_1", "con_dist_2")

val l = cols.map(c => expr(s"percentile_approx($c, Array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) as ${c}_quantiles"))
val df2 = df.filter($"state".isin(states: _*)).groupBy("state").agg(l.head, l.tail: _*)

df2.select(col("state") +: cols.flatMap( c => (1 until 4).map( i => col(c + "_quantiles")(i - 1).alias(c + "_quantile_" + i))): _*).show(false)
```

Here, I tried the automated method for the given `states` and `cols`. The result will be;

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|state|con_dist_1_quantile_1|con_dist_1_quantile_2|con_dist_1_quantile_3|con_dist_2_quantile_1|con_dist_2_quantile_2|con_dist_2_quantile_3|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|AZ   |4                    |4                    |4                    |0.816039063          |0.816039063          |0.816039063          |
|CA   |4                    |4                    |6                    |0.019875458          |0.082049528          |0.816039063          |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Be aware that the result is a bit different with your expected one because I set the `states = Seq("CA", "AZ")` that is given by you.

---

**ORIGINAL**

Use `Window` for the states and calculate the `percent_rank` for each column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w1 = Window.partitionBy("state").orderBy("con_dist_1")
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("state").orderBy("con_dist_2")
df.withColumn("p1", percent_rank.over(w1))
  .withColumn("p2", percent_rank.over(w2))
  .show(false)
```

You may filter the dataframe first, only for specific states. Anyway, the result is:

```
+---+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+---+---+
|id |date     |revenue    |con_dist_1|con_dist_2 |state|p1 |p2 |
+---+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+---+---+
|10 |1/15/2018|0.006628853|4         |0.816039063|AZ   |0.0|0.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.006628853|4         |0.816039063|AZ   |0.0|0.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.010680705|6         |0.019875458|CA   |1.0|0.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.01378215 |4         |0.082049528|CA   |0.0|0.5|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.006628853|4         |0.816039063|CA   |0.0|1.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.010680705|6         |0.019875458|TX   |0.5|0.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.010680705|6         |0.019875458|TX   |0.5|0.0|
|10 |1/15/2018|0.01378215 |4         |0.082049528|TX   |0.0|1.0|
+---+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: I should go home now, I till take a look when I arrive. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do something similar to the below piece of code

```
df.groupBy(col("state"))
    .agg(collect_list(col("con_dist_1")).as("col1_quant"), collect_list(col("con_dist_2")).as("col2_quant"))
    .withColumn("col1_quant1", col("col1_quant")(0))
    .withColumn("col1_quant2", col("col1_quant")(1))
    .withColumn("col2_quant1", col("col2_quant")(0))
    .withColumn("col2_quant2", col("col2_quant")(1))
    .show

OutPut:
+-----+----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|state|col1_quant|          col2_quant|col1_quant1|col1_quant2|col2_quant1|col2_quant2|
+-----+----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   AZ|    [4, 4]|[0.816039063, 0.8...|          4|          4|0.816039063|0.816039063|
|   CA|    [4, 6]|[0.082049528, 0.0...|          4|          6|0.082049528|0.019875458|
|   TX| [6, 4, 6]|[0.019875458, 0.0...|          6|          4|0.019875458|0.082049528|
+-----+----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

may be the last set of withColumn should be inside a loop based on number of records for each state.

Hope this helps!